# get only first image using paperclip rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my post_controller.rb

```
before_action :seo_url,only: [:show]
  def seo_url
    @post = Post.friendly.find params[:id]
  end
```

My post model contains `has_many :uploads` and upload model contains `belongs_to :post`

Here is my `view`

```
<% @post.uploads.each do |image| %>
    <div class="image-thumb">
        <%= image_tag image.upload.url(:thumb) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Thumb working fine but i need to get only `first medium image`

I tried the following to get the medium first image

`<%= image_tag @post.uploads.url(:medium) %>`

But it throws error as

```
undefined method `upload' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Upload:0xb33b7f00>
```

How can i achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this block:

```
<% @post.uploads.each do |image| %>
    <div class="image-thumb">
        <%= image_tag image.upload.url(:thumb) %>  #here!
    </div>
<% end %>
```

You're calling each `upload` as `image` - and then calling `image.upload.url` - which is effectively calling `upload.upload.url`

**Edit**

Working code

```
<%= image_tag @post.uploads.first.upload.url(:medium) %>
```

Comment: I don't have problem in showing thumb images. I need only one medium image.

Comment: ah, sorry maybe i misunderstood - try this: `<%= image_tag @post.uploads.first.url(:medium) %>`

Comment: tried getting error as `undefined method `url' for #<Upload:0x9cb22e0>`

Comment: what does just <%= @post.uploads.first.url %> return?

Comment: getting `undefined method url`

Comment: k, think i've got it - `<%= image_tag @post.uploads.first.upload.url(:medium) %>`